# MongoDB Atlas keeps old data while updating array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I am using Nodejs, Express and MongoDB with Mongoose

MongoDB Schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 category: String,
 projects: Array,
}, {timestamps: true})

export default mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema)
```

insert function:

```
 async insert(data) {
    try {
      let item = await this.model.create(data);
      return item
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

and my update function:

```
async update(id, data) {
 try {
  let item = await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, data);
  return item
 } catch (errors) {
  throw errors;
 } 
}
```

everything works but the update function is not what I expected

projects field data looks like that

projects = [
{
value: Number,
data: Date
},
...
]

for example when i tried to update this created projects field:
[image: from MongoDB Atlas]

just updating existing objects or adding new object but it does not delete removed object. So if I tried to update with that data:

```
  const projects = [
    {
      value: 15,
      date "2022-07-23T18:04:22.661Z"
    },
    {
      value: 20,
      date "2022-07-23T18:04:22.661Z"
    },
  ]
```

i removed the first object but mongodb updating the first and second object but remaining the 3rd object. So it returns like that

```
  [
    {
      value: 15,
      date "2022-07-23T18:04:22.661Z"
    },
    {
      value: 20,
      date "2022-07-23T18:04:22.661Z"
    },
    {
      value: 20,
      date "2022-07-23T18:04:22.661Z"
    },
  ]
```

How can i put my new array instead the old one properly?

Comment: Is it what it returns, or what you have in the database after the update? IIRC for find&update functions to return new value you need to explicitly ask it to do so in the options. Something like `{new: true}`

Comment: thanks for your reply but this {new: true} thing just helps to return the state after the update so i tried that. Also i tried { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: false } options but it dosen't work. { upsert: true } also returning conflict error

Comment: =) just trying different options is not going to work. You posted "So it returns like that", so let me ask it  again - do you confirm the document in the database still have 3 items in the array after the update? And please update the question with what exactly you send as `data` parameter to your `update` function.

Comment: yes after the update still it has 3 items in the array. The two-object data (which i sent) are replacing the first two of the three-object data in the database. Sorry for the way I use English, it's not like my mother tongue, I hope I could explain..

Comment: no worries, I am not a native speaker either, still I believe my question was quite clear - what precisely you are sending to the `update` function as the `data` parameter? Let me rephrase - what operator you use to update projects?

Comment: I think I've given the code that I use above. I am updating with .findByIdAndUpdate(id, data); and my data is like => { name: 'x', category: 'y' , projects: [{..}, ... ] }

Comment: there's no problem with the string fields just array doesn't update as I want

Comment: Your `data` parameter should be `{$set: { name: 'x', category: 'y' , projects: [{..}, ... ] } }`.

Comment: it's nothing change buddy still uptading same